# php oracle connection error

Tags: php, oracle, oracle10g, connection

I have following code

```
$conn = oci_connect('user', 'password', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

I can not connect from my xamp but on live server it works fine

error message is

```
Can't find libclntsh.so.
```

**what i have wrong in my connection ?**

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: what i have wrong in my connection ?

Comment: what error it's showing???

Comment: Can't find libclntsh.so.

Answer (score 1):

issue was with php.ini file it needed enable

```
extension=oci8.so
```

thank you to all